# Hi! how can I remove all non-numeric characters with a regex, leaving ab3f4 // => 34

Tags: javascript

how can I remove all non-numeric characters with a regex, leaving ab3f4 // => 34 (using javascript)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Questions should show previous research.

Comment: Searching for this would have yielded multiple answers. That said: I'd recommend spending an hour going through some basic regex tutorials; regexes are one of the tools that should be in everyone's toolbox. Their importance cannot be overstated, across domains and ecosystems. (With the caveat that they're not the best solution for *every* task: when regexes are your hammer everything looks like a thumb.)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score -2):

Just do `.replace(/\D/g, '')`:

```js
console.log('ab3f4'.replace(/\D/g, ''))
```

Comment: A downvote for a correct answer on a poor question, IMO, is an abuse of downvoting. YMMV.

Comment: @DaveNewton while I agree, it doesn't really matter to me, I answer to be helpful not because I care about the points